# the meaning of on-the-nose lines

Tags: phrase-meaning

> They’re not really characters, but mouthpieces delivering **on-the-nose lines**—“The only man I let walk all over me is you,” Emily says—leaving Dynevor and Ehrenreich, both capable actors, lost in their roles. [From an article in the Atlantic](https://www.theatlantic.com/culture/archive/2023/10/fair-play-movie-review-netflix/675489/?taid=6527ab07f3ab4f00019b3bb2&utm_campaign=the-atlantic&utm_content=true-anthem&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter)

I've found nothing useful to explain **on-the-nose lines** from dictionaries. I would like to figure it out. How could it be about the nose?

Comment: “Get it through”? Maybe “figure it out”? Or “make heads or tails of it”?

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nose) defines the phrase *on the nose*. Does that help?

Comment: 'Accurately' seems to work here. But in this case, I'm struggling to understand the meaning of lines following the on the nose.

Comment: It appears to me that Emily is using a variant of an expression from theater, *to step on someone’s line*, which means to say a line or perform some bit of onstage business too quickly after another actor has finished theirs, thus reducing its effect for the audience.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum: I think you read too much into that line. Imho the article writer just thinks it's a "powerful, emotive" line ("on-the-nose", accurately describing her attitude to men in general and him in particular). BUT the writer thinks although the script is chock-full of such "memorable" lines, the actual ***storyline*** is sloppily and unconvincingly portrayed, so even though the two lead actors are highly competent, there's not much they can do with such a poor quality script.

Comment: Wow, @FumbleFingers, that’s a lot to take from the passage. And **I** read too much into it? Hmm.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum: Well, I did skim through the article itself. The OP's link leads to a paywalled site, but I just searched for "delivering on-the-nose lines" and found the full article somewhere else. Besides which, I think ***if*** the cited line in the script had any allusion to the thespian idiom "step on someone’s line", that would be a major "break in the fourth wall" (between fictitious characters and *actual* audience), so any critical review would be practically *bound* to explicitly mention it.

Comment: [Related question from EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/248474/what-does-too-on-the-nose-mean)

Comment: At one point (maybe still?) it was fashionable to discipline puppies who misbehaved by hitting them (gently) on the nose with a rolled-up newspaper.  This phrase always conveyed to me the image of the scriptwriter hitting the audience on the nose with a rolled-up copy of the movie's script, in effect saying "HERE!  SEE!  THIS IS THE MESSAGE I WANT YOU TO RECEIVE!"

Comment: I haven't heard of anything like 'on-the-nose lines' In 60 years of listening.

If I had to, I'd guess that meant something like 'a comment so painful, it felt like being smacked on the nose…'

I see how it could also mean 'right on target' and who sees a significant difference, except whether the end is good or bad?

Answer (score 17):

As noted in the comments, the expression is defined as "accurate, on target". But that doesn't convey enough of what it means in this context.

It's a pejorative expression when it comes to the dialogue in a movie. It means that the sentiments are expressed with implausible aptness or pithiness. The dialogue is stereotypical; it too perfectly fits the genre (the "target"). This makes it unsubtle and unrealistic. Hence, the characters are "not really characters", but tropes — and in this case no more than "mouthpieces" for a screenwriter who is, presumably, [too clever by half](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/too-clever-by-half).

---

Another sense that is not intended in this context is when one explicitly calls someone out for something that it's a [faux pas](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/faux%20pas) to name, or directs an insult at them that hits too close to home, i.e. to a sore spot. The receiver of the remark might then say:

> That was a little on-the-nose!

Comment: I think you're exactly right, and "implausible aptness or pithiness" is itself *on the nose, on the button* (you've *hit the nail on the head* with those words). I don't use *on the nose* myself (too close by *winning **by a nose*** = by a narrow margin), so I looked at ***is right on the nose*** and ***is right on the button***  in NGrams. They're now about equally common in AmE, with the "nose" version on the ascendant, but that version is too uncommon to even show in the chart with the BrE corpus. For your final context, Brits say *That was a little **near the mark**!*

Comment: My understanding is it refers not to dialogue that's too apt or pithy but to characters who always say exactly what they're thinking in the most direct manner. "That makes me angry!" is a stereotypical example. A character should show their anger, not announce it.

Comment: @KefSchecter While that's a possible definition (and closer to the second part of my answer), I don't think that's what's meant in the context of the article. That fault doesn't make characters into mouthpieces for the screenwriter.